# Como quitar el ultimo punto y coma sql 2014

Tags: sql

una consulta. Como puedo quitar el ultimo punto y coma de los registros que me arroja esta query. Lo he intentado con sl substring y no me funciona

```
select  Areas = STUFF(
    (
      SELECT '; ' + v
      --FROM (VALUES (A.Area1),  (A.Area2emis )) AS v (v)

      --SELECT Rut, LEFT(Rut,CHARINDEX('-',Rut)-1) Rut_Sin_DV FROM dbo.YourTable;
        --substring(A.Area58emis, 1, (len(A.Area58emis) - 1)) as Area58emis,
      fROM (VALUES (SUBSTRING (A.Area1 ,1, len(A.Area1) -1 )), ((CASE WHEN A.Area2emis='0'  THEN '' ELSE A.Area2emis END ))) AS v (v)
      FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
    1, 2, '') from Area1 A 
    INNER JOIN MotoresEmis M
    ON A.Area1<>'' and A.Area1<>'0' and A.Area1<>'---' 
    AND M.ID=A.IdTitulo
    AND M.Titulo='MOTORES EMIS'
    --AND M.Clave='851-03-F3'
    GROUP BY A.Area1,A.Area2emis
 order by A.Area1 asc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál último punto y coma? Será la edad, pero no veo ningún campo de todos los registros que tenga un punto y coma al final (quizás tu y yo entendemos diferente que es el último punto y coma). Por otro lado, en etiquetas, a tu pregunta le falta indicar el motor que  usas (yo se cual es, pero la etiqueta debieras ponerla tu).

Comment: Hola que tal. Por ej el primer registro de la imagen. 3Q6 tiene el punto y coma al final amigo. Lo que quiero es quitar ese carácter.

Comment: El segundo no lo tiene, es decir, no es algo que produzca la consulta, sino que está en los datos. Si está en los datos, no es necesario meter una consulta tan compleja a la pregunta, puedes hacer un [mcve] que sea realmente mínimo, es decir, simple.

Comment: Es correcto hay veces que un registro va traer mas de dos áreas. Y cuando sean mas de dos areas lo que busco es concatenar la segunda area separadas por punto y coma. La consulta me arroja correcto los datos. El detalle que cuando un registro trae una sola area le pone el punto y coma al final. Y es lo que busco eliminar. No se si me explico. Saludos y gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa con el 5 y el 6, ambos parecen tener un _área_ y uno tiene `;` y el otro no?

Comment: Alguna recomendación de como hacerlo? Cualquier idea es bienvenida.

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien mas le sirve. Lo consegui de esta forma..

Saludos!!

```
    select 
    left(right(A.Area1,len(A.Area1) - patindex('%[^, ]%',A.Area1) + 3)
        ,len(right(A.Area1,len(A.Area1) - patindex('%[^, ]%',A.Area1) + 3)) - patindex('%[^, ]%',reverse(right(A.Area1,len(A.Area1) - patindex('%[^, ]%',A.Area1) + 3))) + 3) AS Area1
        From Area1_5mayo A 
    INNER JOIN MotoresEmis M
    ON A.Area1<>'' and A.Area1<>'0' and A.Area1<>'---' 
    AND M.ID=A.IdTitulo
    AND M.Titulo='MOTORES EMIS'
    group by A.Area1
    order by A.Area1 asc
```